# Cannot install better-sqlite3 package on MacOS Ventura

Tags: macos, node-gyp, darwin, macos-ventura, better-sqlite3

I am trying to install the Node.js package `better-sqlite3` on my Strapi App, on my new laptop, a MacBook Pro M2 running on MacOS Ventura `13.2.1`. It is not successful because, from what I understood, there are packages missing, and specifically while running the `make` command during the build process of `node-gyp` (I don't think it is specific for my laptop, because I have seen other people in the same case on Internet, but without a good solution).


I tried to install Xcode but it didn't change anything.
I tried to install autoconf, automake, libtool, pkg-config with brew (because I have seen it was maybe the equivalent of build-tools of Linux on MacOS), but same result. 
I also tried to execute `xcode-select --install`, but was already installed.


I lastly tried on my former laptop - which is a MacBook Pro Intel, running on MacOS Monterey `12.5`, it is working perfectly (which is proving thus that it is an error occurring only on the new version)


Here is the error printed on the terminal :

```bash
error /Users/Maxime/Desktop/Projets de code/mh-info.fr/backend/node_modules/better-sqlite3: Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: prebuild-install || node-gyp rebuild --release
Arguments: 
Directory: /Users/Maxime/Desktop/Projets de code/mh-info.fr/backend/node_modules/better-sqlite3
Output:
prebuild-install warn install No prebuilt binaries found (target=16.15.1 runtime=node arch=arm64 libc= platform=darwin)
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@9.3.1
gyp info using node@16.15.1 | darwin | arm64
gyp info find Python using Python version 3.9.0 found at "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3"
gyp info spawn /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3
gyp info spawn args [
gyp info spawn args   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-f',
gyp info spawn args   'make',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/Users/Maxime/Desktop/Projets de code/mh-info.fr/backend/node_modules/better-sqlite3/build/config.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/Users/Maxime/Library/Caches/node-gyp/16.15.1/include/node/common.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/Users/Maxime/Library/Caches/node-gyp/16.15.1',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/Users/Maxime/Library/Caches/node-gyp/16.15.1/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/Users/Maxime/Desktop/Projets de code/mh-info.fr/backend/node_modules/better-sqlite3',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
gyp info spawn args   'build',
gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
gyp info spawn args ]
gyp info spawn make
gyp info spawn args [ 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]
  TOUCH ba23eeee118cd63e16015df367567cb043fed872.intermediate
  ACTION deps_sqlite3_gyp_locate_sqlite3_target_copy_builtin_sqlite3 ba23eeee118cd63e16015df367567cb043fed872.intermediate
/bin/sh: de: command not found
node:internal/fs/utils:345
    throw err;
    ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, copyfile '/Users/Maxime/Desktop/Projets de code/mh-info.fr/backend/node_modules/better-sqlite3/deps/sqlite3/sqlite3.c' -> '/Users/Maxime/Desktop/Projets de code/mh-info.fr/backend/node_modules/better-sqlite3/build/Release/obj/gen/sqlite3/sqlite3.c'
    at Object.copyFileSync (node:fs:2817:3)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/Maxime/Desktop/Projets de code/mh-info.fr/backend/node_modules/better-sqlite3/deps/copy.js:25:5)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  errno: -2,
  syscall: 'copyfile',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  path: '/Users/Maxime/Desktop/Projets de code/mh-info.fr/backend/node_modules/better-sqlite3/deps/sqlite3/sqlite3.c',
  dest: '/Users/Maxime/Desktop/Projets de code/mh-info.fr/backend/node_modules/better-sqlite3/build/Release/obj/gen/sqlite3/sqlite3.c'
}
make: *** [ba23eeee118cd63e16015df367567cb043fed872.intermediate] Error 1
rm ba23eeee118cd63e16015df367567cb043fed872.intermediate
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:203:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:527:28)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 22.3.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--release"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/Maxime/Desktop/Projets de code/mh-info.fr/backend/node_modules/better-sqlite3
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, Sorry! it was just a stupid bug : I had a folder with spaces in the name, and this caused to create a false path to `/Users/Maxime/Desktop/Projets de code/mh-info.fr/backend/node_modules/better-sqlite3/deps/sqlite3/sqlite3.c`